# What is the integer value that gives a broadcast receiver highest priority?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

What is the integer value the gives a broadcast receiver the highest priority?

```
<intent-filter android:priority="1">
  <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Well, according to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html)

```
"The value must be an integer, such as "100". Higher numbers have a higher priority."
```

So I'm guessing that any integer value is valid.  And the highest priority possible would be the maximum integer that android allows, which is (2^31 - 1).

**EDIT**

The documentation has been updated, and it now explicitly states which priority values may be used by applications.  The documentation now says

> SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY (1000): Applications should never use filters
>   with this or higher priorities.
>   SYSTEM_LOW_PRIORITY (-1000): Applications should never use filters
>   with this or lower priorities.

Implying that your application is permitted to use integer priority levels between -999 and 999.

Comment: Your guess is wrong, look at the answer of @wasaig. edit your answer for the interest of community.

Comment: Actually, this is the correct answer, it is a quote directly from Google's documentation.

Comment: Setting 999 is slower for me. 2^31 - 1 is much faster than 999. I am sticking with 2^31 - 1.

Answer (score 19):

Well the system highest priority is 1000. You can refer to this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html#SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY) to know more.

Comment: No, it's 999. `SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY (Constant Value: 1000) Applications should never use filters with this or higher priorities.`

Answer (score 5):

Actually, numbers above 1000 grant more priority, despite [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter#SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY). So the highest integer number(2147483647) grants more priority.

Comment: Yes, 2147483647 is giving better results for me.

Answer (score 2):

Applications should avoid using filters with "this" or higher priorities. "this" refers to the value "1000"

Answer (score 2):

Google suggests that: The value must be an integer, such as "100". Higher numbers have a higher priority. The default value is 0. The value must be greater than -1000 and less than 1000.http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html
But in the projects, we often use the highest integer number(2147483647) (2 ^32-1)) or others;it is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

999 gives a broadcast receiver the highest priority.

As per Android Documentation: Applications must use a value that is larger than SYSTEM_LOW_PRIORITY and smaller than SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY.
The value of SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY is 1000.

References: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html